# Transform List(Of DerivedObject) to List(Of BaseObject)

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

Say, I have a fonction that operates a list of base objects. But I have a list of derived objects. What is the most efficient way to transform it?

Let's have

```
Public Sub Main
  ...
  Dim myButtons as List(Of Button) = Me.GetMyButtons()
  Me.Delete(?? transform myButtons to myControls??)
  ...
End Sub 

Public Sub Delete(controls as List(Of Control)) ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `List(Of T).ConvertAll`, or just use `Cast(Of T)` and `ToList`. My VB syntax may be wrong, but:

```
Me.Delete(myButtons.ConvertAll(Function(b) CType(b, Control)))
```

or

```
Me.Delete(myButtons.Cast(Of Control)().ToList())
```

Alternatively, if you're using .NET 4 (with its generic covariance) you could just use:

```
Me.Delete(myButtons.ToList(Of Control)())
```

or even better, just change the signature of `Delete` to:

```
Public Sub Delete(controls as IEnumerable(Of Control)) ...
```

Comment: I can't change the signature of Delete, I have a crazy team... Thanks! Better was to change the signature of Delete with the List of Button... in my case...

Comment: @moldovanu: There's nothing crazy about wanting Option Strict On (quite the reverse - I'd say it's crazy to want it *off* most of the time), but you could still change the signature to the last version and use generic covariance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq's [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) if you need an explicit conversion, [ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx), or [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) if it can be accomplished as a cast.